# How I can decode TIdMessage from koi8-r to windows-1251?

Tags: indy, pop3, indy10

I use Embarcadero C++Builder 10.2 Tokyo with Indy 10.

The task is to check emails via POP3. I can get emails, but I don't know how to decode their subjects, attachment file name, etc from koi8-r to windows-1251 or UTF-8.

Can anybody help me?

The code is:

```
int nMess = pop3->CheckMessages();
if (nMess == 0) return;
for (int i = 1; i <= nMess; i++) {
    pop3->UIDL(sl,i);   // check for UID
    UnicodeString sUID = sl->Strings[0];   // get one of them
    if (isLetterYetRead(sUID,_idBox)) continue;
    // if new, read it
    pop3->Retrieve(i,IdMessage1);
    int mSize = pop3->RetrieveMsgSize(i);
    // parsing
    for (int j = 0; j < IdMessage1->MessageParts->Count; j++) {
        TIdMessagePart *mp = IdMessage1->MessageParts->Items[j];
        // attacnets later
        if (mp->PartType() == mptAttachment) continue;
        TIdText *pt = (TIdText*) mp;
        if (pt->ContentType == "text/plain" )
            plain = pt->Body->Text;
        else if (pt->ContentType == "text/html" ) {
            html = pt->Body->Text;
            //  ??? bool g = NeedConvertToUnicode(IdMessage1->,pt->);
        }
    }
}
```

How to decode non-english fields?

Comment: C++Builder 10 uses UTF-16 encoded Unicode strings, you don't want things decoded to Win1251, that would be lossy. Indy decodes MIME-encoded (RFC 2047) headers to UTF-16 for you, so you don't need to decode them manually (unless they are malformed). If you have an email that is not decoding the way you expect, please show the actual email.

Answer (score 0):

The email is:

```
`    Return-path: <babichev@meccanosoft.com>
     Envelope-to: ear@meccanosoft.com
     Delivery-date: Thu, 12 Jul 2018 14:00:33 +0300
     Received: from [213.79.95.226] (helo=pccomerc)
     by server120.hosting.reg.ru with esmtpa (Exim 4.90_1)
     (envelope-from <babichev@meccanosoft.com>)
     id 1fdZKr-0002FS-1c
     for ear@meccanosoft.com; Thu, 12 Jul 2018 14:00:33 +0300
     From: =?KOI8-R?B?4sHCyd7F1yDzxdLHxco=?= <babichev@meccanosoft.com>
     To: ear@meccanosoft.com
     Subject: test8
     Date: Thu, 12 Jul 2018 14:00:29 +0300
     Message-Id: <006901d419cf$8e2aeed0$aa80cc70$@meccanosoft.com>
     MIME-Version: 1.0
     Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="UMwhv1yjwbAJnDKFK8wyCH0CYSe2=_553g"
     X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook 16.0
     Thread-Index: AdQZz4RBq8MEckA1Rq6W+ide2hSKlw==
     Content-Language: ru
     In-Reply-To: <006901d419cf$8e2aeed0$aa80cc70$@meccanosoft.com>

     This is a multipart message in MIME format.

     --UMwhv1yjwbAJnDKFK8wyCH0CYSe2=_553g
     Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
     boundary="jEgWjeMCC35bF=_m8mr8EoHknZfRtWVKzB"

     --jEgWjeMCC35bF=_m8mr8EoHknZfRtWVKzB
     Content-Type: text/plain; charset="koi8-r"
     Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
     Content-Disposition: inline

     TEST8


     --jEgWjeMCC35bF=_m8mr8EoHknZfRtWVKzB
     Content-Type: text/html; charset="koi8-r"
     Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
     Content-Disposition: inline

     <html xmlns:v=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o=3D"urn:schemas=
     -microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:off=
     ice:word" xmlns:m=3D"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"=
     xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta http-equiv=3DCo=
     ntent-Type content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dkoi8-r"><meta name=3DGenera=
     tor content=3D"Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)"><style><!--
     /* Font Definitions */
     @font-face
        {font-family:"Cambria Math";
        panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
     @font-face
      {font-family:Calibri;
      panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
    /* Style Definitions */
    p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
      {margin:0cm;
      margin-bottom:.0001pt;
        font-size:11.0pt;
        font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
        mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}
     a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:#0563C1;
    text-decoration:underline;}
    a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:#954F72;
    text-decoration:underline;}
    span.EmailStyle17
    {mso-style-type:personal-compose;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    color:windowtext;}
     =2EMsoChpDefault
      {mso-style-type:export-only;
      font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
        mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}
    @page WordSection1
    {size:612.0pt 792.0pt;
    margin:2.0cm 42.5pt 2.0cm 3.0cm;}
    div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
     --></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
    <o:shapedefaults v:ext=3D"edit" spidmax=3D"1026" />
    </xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
    <o:shapelayout v:ext=3D"edit">
    <o:idmap v:ext=3D"edit" data=3D"1" />
    </o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body lang=3DRU link=3D"#0563=
    C1" vlink=3D"#954F72"><div class=3DWordSection1><p class=3DMsoNormal><=
    span lang=3DEN-US>TEST8<o:p></o:p></span></p></div></body></html>

    --jEgWjeMCC35bF=_m8mr8EoHknZfRtWVKzB--

    --UMwhv1yjwbAJnDKFK8wyCH0CYSe2=_553g
    Content-Type: text/plain;
    name="=?KOI8-R?B?0M/e1MExLnR4dA==?="
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
    Content-Disposition: attachment;
    filename="=?KOI8-R?B?0M/e1MExLnR4dA==?="
    ................................................
    --UMwhv1yjwbAJnDKFK8wyCH0CYSe2=_553g--
`
```

Result of receiving is:

[List of letters after receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILA36.jpg)
Code is:

```
     `  TIdPOP3 *pop3 = new TIdPOP3 ();
        TIdMessage *IdMessage1 = new TIdMessage();
        pop3->Host = qPop3->FieldByName("pop3server")->AsString;
        pop3->Port = qPop3->FieldByName("pop3port")->AsInteger;
        pop3->Username =  qPop3->FieldByName("pop3login")->AsString;
        pop3->Password = password;
        pop3->Connect();

        int nMess = pop3->CheckMessages();
        if (nMess == 0) return;
        for (int i = 1; i <= nMess; i++) {
           pop3->UIDL(sl,i);   // ask for UID
           UnicodeString sUID = sl->Strings[0]; 
           pop3->Retrieve(i,IdMessage1);
           int mSize = pop3->RetrieveMsgSize(i);
           UnicodeString s = L"c:\\Temp\\"+sUID+".eml";
           IdMessage1->SaveToFile(s,false);   
        // Parsing
           for (int j = 0; j < IdMessage1->MessageParts->Count; j++) {
               TIdMessagePart *mp = IdMessage1->MessageParts->Items[j];
       //   -------- and etc -------------
           }
       }
`
```

Sure I do something wrong, but what?